# Keyboard is pushing tabs and app's contents ionic 3 in Android

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, keyboard, ionic3

I'm developing an app on IONIC 3 and i’m having a problem.
When I click on the ion search and the Keyboard opens in ANDROID
it simply pushes the entire contents of the App by breaking the layout 
and squeezing the content.

normal screen:

[image]

Keyboard  mode on:

[image]

I had already tried:

app.module.ts scrollAssist: false,

autoFocusAssist: false,

and also: this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);

and:  this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);

IOS works just the way I want it

The problem only happens on this screen that has the TABS. On
other screens it works exactly the way I need it, it opens the keyboard without pushing anything.

**IONIC INFO:**

**cli packages:**

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.1
```

**global packages:**

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

**local packages:**

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.1 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

**System:**

```
ios-sim : 5.1.0 
Node    : v6.11.0
npm     : 3.10.10 
OS      : macOS Sierra
Xcode   : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

**My HTML:**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color = "festow-primary">
    <botão botão íon menuToggle>
      <icon-icon name = "menu"> </ ion-icon>
    </ button>
    <ion-title> Festas em {{cidadeCodigo}} </ ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <botão (clique) = "modalPesquisa ()" ícone-botão apenas ícone
        <icon-icon name = "ios-funnel"> </ ion-icon>
      </ button>
    </ ion-buttons>
  </ ion-navbar>

</ ion-header>


<ion-content class = "teste">
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh) = "doRefresh ($ event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon = "seta-seta"
      pullingText = "Puxe para atualizar"
      refrescanteSpinner = "círculos"
      refreshingText = "Atualizando ...">
    </ ion-refresher-content>
  </ ion-refresher>
  <ion-searchbar * ngIf = "festa"
  espaço reservado = "Pesquise ..."
  [(ngModel)] = "myInput"
  (ionInput) = "onInput ($ event)">
</ ion-searchbar>

  <ion-card * ngFor = "deixe festa de festa" class = "cards card-full" style = "border-color: #ffffff! important;">

    <img class = "cartões de imagem" src = "http://festow.com/images/{{festa.thumb}}" height = "42%" style = "border-color: #ffffff! important;">
    <ion-fab center edge class = "fab-cards">
        <button ion-fab mini class = "fab-button" (clique) = "itemTapped ($ event, festa)"> <icon-icon name = "add"> </ ion-icon> </ button>
      </ ion-fab>
    <classe de conteúdo de cartão de íon = "cartão-conteúdo-cor grade-preenchimento">
      <classe ión-grade = "grade-preenchimento">
        <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6 col-sm>
      <p class = "p-cards fonte"> {{festa.nome}} </ p>
      <p class = "p-cards fonte"> {{festa.horario}} - {{festa.hora_fim}} </ p>
      </ ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4 col-sm offset-2>
      <p class = "p-cards fonte"> {{festa.nome_casa}} </ p>
      <p class = "p-cards"> <rating [score] = "festa.estrelas" max = "5"> </ rating> </ p>
      </ ion-col>
        </ ion-row>
      </ ion-grid>

    </ ion-card-content>

  </ ion-card>
</ ion-content>
```

**My TS:**

```
ngOnInit () {
    // this.keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    // this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);
      this.presentLoading ();

      setTimeout (() => {
      this.festaService.loadFestas (this.cidadeCodigo) .subscribe (
        dados => {
            this.loader.dismiss ();
            se (dados ['erro'] == falso)
            {

          this.festa = data.festa;
          this.nomeFesta = data.festa.nome;
          console.log (data.festa)

              Deixe o alerta = this.alertCtrl.create ({
                Título: 'Pronto!',
                subtítulo: 'Essas são como festas que hoje estão em' + this.cidadeCodigo + '.',
                botões: [
              {
                Texto: 'OK'
                manipulador: dados => {
                }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present ();
            }outro{
              this.naotem = '1';
              Deixe o alerta = this.alertCtrl.create ({
                Título: 'Pronto!',
                subtítulo: 'Não encontramos festas hoje em' + this.cidadeCodigo + '.',
                botões: [
              {
                Texto: 'OK'
                manipulador: dados => {
                }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present ();
            }
        },
        err => {
          console.log (err);
        },
        () => console.log ('festas complet')
    );
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: Hope you'll change your name's  `Suicide` part. Please don't give bad moral to others. It'll backfire on you. Bad Karma will chase you. Please change it. @CommercialSuicide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ion-grid` as shown below. Can you try that and let us know?

.html

```
<ion-content class = "teste">
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
       <ion-refresher (ionRefresh) = "doRefresh ($ event)">
       <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon = "seta-seta"
      pullingText = "Puxe para atualizar"
      refrescanteSpinner = "círculos"
      refreshingText = "Atualizando ...">
    </ ion-refresher-content>
  </ ion-refresher>
  <ion-searchbar * ngIf = "festa"
  espaço reservado = "Pesquise ..."
  [(ngModel)] = "myInput"
  (ionInput) = "onInput ($ event)">
</ ion-searchbar>

  <ion-card * ngFor = "deixe festa de festa" class = "cards card-full" style = "border-color: #ffffff! important;">

    <img class = "cartões de imagem" src = "http://festow.com/images/{{festa.thumb}}" height = "42%" style = "border-color: #ffffff! important;">
    <ion-fab center edge class = "fab-cards">
        <button ion-fab mini class = "fab-button" (clique) = "itemTapped ($ event, festa)"> <icon-icon name = "add"> </ ion-icon> </ button>
      </ ion-fab>
    <classe de conteúdo de cartão de íon = "cartão-conteúdo-cor grade-preenchimento">
      <classe ión-grade = "grade-preenchimento">
        <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6 col-sm>
      <p class = "p-cards fonte"> {{festa.nome}} </ p>
      <p class = "p-cards fonte"> {{festa.horario}} - {{festa.hora_fim}} </ p>
      </ ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4 col-sm offset-2>
      <p class = "p-cards fonte"> {{festa.nome_casa}} </ p>
      <p class = "p-cards"> <rating [score] = "festa.estrelas" max = "5"> </ rating> </ p>
      </ ion-col>
        </ ion-row>
      </ ion-grid>

    </ ion-card-content>

    </ ion-card>
   </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
</ ion-content>
```

*your-page.scss*

```
page-my{
    .teste {
       ion-grid {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you see is that apply correctly? maybe you need `!important`

Comment: yes, I used the !important, as I explained in the screenshots above, this problem only happens in the TABS pages, it seems that the TABS decrease the content causing the error.

Comment: Still having the same problem :(

Comment: Here you can see the same kind of issue no. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537611/ionic-webview-for-android-makes-the-whole-division-shift-up-while-clicking-on-in

Comment: Sorry for the lousy English, I'm using google to translate.

My problem is similar to this, but as I said in the text above, in other screens I have no problem, I click on "inputs" and the keyboard does not squeeze the contents. As I said, my problem is only on the TABS page, it seems that when the TABS goes up, they force the contents of the screen to decrease.

Comment: Can't you apply the same pattern to your `tabs.html` page then?

Comment: Someone has found a solution? I am using ion-list and same problem occurs... driving me crazy