# Ionic webview for android makes the whole division shift up while clicking on input boxed

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic v3.10, below is my login HTML code

```
    <ion-content>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-12>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-card>
                    <ion-card-header>
                        <ion-img style="background-color: transparent; display: block; margin: auto;" height="100" width="100" src="assets/logo.png" alt="iBin"></ion-img>
                    </ion-card-header>
                    <ion-card-content>
                        <ion-item ion-fixed>
                            <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
                            <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item ion-fixed>
                            <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
                            <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            <!-- <button ion-button color="secondary" outline padding >Login</button> -->
                            <button ion-button color="secondary" outline padding block round (click)="login()">Login</button>
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-card-content>

                </ion-card>
            </ion-list>
           </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

The scss i have applied is

```
page-home
        {
            ion-grid, ion-card-content
                {
                    min-height: 100%;
                }
        }
```

The problem with this code this that whenever I run the command `ionic serve -l` it renders the 3 basic views i.e ios, android, and windows. There are two input boxes one is for username and 2nd is for the password. Whenever I click on the input box in the android view the whole division shifts up.

But when I do the click in windows or ios windows it works all fine. I even tried applying `ion-fixed` to the `ion-content` but then it makes the whole ui shrinked to 50%

What might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and let us know?

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-card>
                <ion-item ion-fixed>
                    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item ion-fixed>
                    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
                    <ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <!-- <button ion-button color="secondary" outline padding >Login</button> -->
                    <button ion-button color="secondary" outline padding block round (click)="login()">Login</button>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-list>
       </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
     </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

*.scss*

```
 page-my {
    ion-grid {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Yups that worked fine but what was the reason behind it?

Comment: Oh i see, but i hope it doesn't fail at some pint ;)

Comment: I have used it with my apps and no issue at all so far :)

Comment: Hello @Sampath please see the question I have updated it again. The problem again persists after I have done some code formatting.

Comment: This is wrong `, ion-card-content`. You need to remove it. Just use like this:  `ion-grid {
            min-height: 100%;
        }`

Comment: Use `min-height: 100% !important;`. Hope you test this on device right?

Comment: actually i am testing it through `ionic serve -l` the first time it worked then i did some formatting and again it started like the first time.